# Turtle not displaying on screen - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to recreate the snake game, however when I call the function which is supposed to create the initial body of the snake nothing appears on the screen.

The same problem happens if I simply create a turtle object in the main file.

Snake:

```
 from turtle import Turtle

STARTING_POSITIONS = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]


class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.segments = []
        self.create_snake()


    def create_snake (self):
        for position in STARTING_POSITIONS:
            n_segment = Turtle("square")
            n_segment.color("white")
            n_segment.penup()
            print(position)
            n_segment.goto(position)
            self.segments.append(n_segment)
```

Main:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from snake import Snake

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width = 600 , height= 600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("SNAKE")
screen.tracer(0)
game_on = True
segments = []


snake = Snake()
turtle = Turtle()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see the snake, I just added the following code snippet in main.py after the turtle definition to display a stationary snake with a pointer.

```
while game_on:
    screen.update() 

screen.exitonclick()
```

The result was this image.

[image: Snake Image]

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

this is a minimum reproducible example of the above code which works and draws a square (segment of the snake body) in the snake class:

```py
import turtle as ttl


class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.segments = []
        self.create_snake()


    def create_snake (self):
        ttl.shape('square')
        ttl.color('white')


screen = ttl.Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor('black')

snake = Snake()
ttl.done()
```

A lot of the code from the OP question is removed because there were numerous errors. Also, for the purpose of simplicity the class was added to the code, but the OP could break it into two separate files if desired.

I believe that there error in the question code was that the screen was drawing over itself which is why it was always black.

You can build from here.